# How to create an external menu link with some arguments?

Tags: 8

I`m trying to create Main menu item with external URL. This code is good for me

```
    $path = 'https://backend.supplysolver.com/startApp/' . $uid . '/' . $userKey . '/' . $currentLang;
  MenuLinkContent::create([
    'title'     => 'start Application',
    'link'      => ['uri' => $path],
    'menu_name' => 'main',
    'target'    => '_blank',
    'external'  => TRUE
  ])->save();
```

When I use this code in preprocess_page Menu item is duplicating. Please help

Comment: MenuLinkContent is used to create permanent menu links in a menu, and so each time your page is rendered it is creating menu links. Do you want to store the external links in the actual menu, or render hard-coded external links in your template?

Comment: I think the intent is to create anchor elements with dynamic path elements in a template, and not add dynamic menu links to a menu, but I could be mistaken. If it's the latter, then the solution would be to add menu route that does the external redirect.

Comment: Redirect from internal page sounds good, but I have problem with Url::fromUli because it takes only string. How should I make this redirect?

Comment: No need answer. Created redirect from internal page. Thanks for idea